# Greedy Regex isn't behaving greedily

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to scrape a URL with Regex, but there must be something I don't get about Regex. Here's my Regex

```
public static Regex newSite = new Regex("=['\"]https?://[A-Za-z0-9\\.]*(?<url>\\w+)\\.(?<ext>[A-Za-z]{2,3})(?<deep>.+)?[/?'\"]");
//...
MatchCollection newSites = newSite.Matches(input);
```

According to what I've read, in the `<url>` group, the greedy `+` is supposed to capture as many characters as possible. So for an input of `https://www.digitalocean.com`, it should match `digitalocean`. My Regex matched the input successfully, but the Match is only capturing the last letter, `n`. The MatchCollection contains

```
Groups->
    Count 4:
    [0]: https://www.digitalocean.com/assets/...
    [1]: n
    [2]: com
    [3]: /assets/...
```

How do I get the group to capture everything?

Comment: Because `[A-Za-z0-9\\.]*` is greedy too and is before your group (the leftmost wins).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ah. That was quick, thanks! The solution is to change to "=['\"]https?://[A-Za-z0-9]*\\.?(?<url>\\w+)\\.(?<ext>[A-Za-z]{2,3})(?<deep>.+)?[/?'\"]" I believe

Comment: Perhaps, it depends what you exactly want to do. What if the domain contains more than two subdomains?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Perhaps I should just forget about trying to trim off the `www.` part. But how can I tell it grab everything between http:// and .com if there's zero or more periods in between?

Comment: The regex doesn't match `https://www.digitalocean.com`. This does `https?://[A-Za-z0-9\.]*(?<url>\w+)\.(?<ext>[A-Za-z]{2,3})` The equivalent to get everything past the device up to the final segment can be this `https?://(?!_)([\w.]*)\.(?<ext>[A-Za-z]{2,3})` where it is in group 1.